# How to get exact match data from another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I have data in "Database" worksheet as shown below:

[image]

I have written a short code to get the data matching with certain criteria from "Database" sheet and paste it on another sheet "SelectedRecords"

Here is my code

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim db As Worksheet
Dim rcd As Worksheet

Set db = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
Set rcd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SelectedRecords")

db.Range("A1:C7").AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("$A$1:$A$2"), _
    CopyToRange:=rcd.Range("$A$4:$B$4")

End Sub
```

This code is working but I am getting some additional records as shown below:

[image]

I am looking for data where Name = "Jack" but in output I am getting all the data starting with "Jack". How can I get records that are exactly matching criteria mentioned in A2 cell. In this case my output should only give one record for "Jack".

Other two records "JackSparrow" and "Jackson" should be filtered out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default you will get all matches. Right now cell `A2` in `SelectedRecords` has `Jack`. To get the exact match, change it to `="=Jack"` as shown below and then try again.

[image]

Alternative if you do not want to type "=" everytime then use a helper column as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @Siddharth_Rout's answer you can use it like this code in your VBA:

```
Dim db As Worksheet
Dim rcd As Worksheet

Set db = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
Set rcd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SelectedRecords")

' Here a "=" will added at beginning if it's not typed
If (Left(rcd.Range("$A$2").Value, 1) <> "=") Then
    rcd.Range("$A$2").Value = "'=" & rcd.Range("$A$2").Value
    '                          ^ this quote is required to avoiding calculation 
End If

db.Range("A1:C7").AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=rcd.Range("$A$1:$A$2"), _
    CopyToRange:=rcd.Range("$A$4:$B$4")
```