# Advanced Filter returning wildcard data (no wildcards used)

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I've got a large data set I'm using Advanced Filter to sort through. It's working well for the most part but I've come across an issue I'm not really sure how to deal with.

I have a list of criteria that corresponds to what is in the data table,

Let's say the criteria are
Food - Dessert - Apple

Advanced Filter is returning not just all the results for "apple" but also for "apple pie", "apple cobbler" etc.

Is there a way I can set this to only return the term being searched for rather than including records that also contain that string?

I've tried inserting quotations around it but that predictably failed.

If anyone has any ideas I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks!

```
Dim Grp1Criteria As Range: Set Grp1Criteria = WsCriteriaSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    If DataSheet.FilterMode Then
        DataSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
    
    WholeMainTable.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, Grp1Criteria
```

Note: Current region is isolated so that it's only containing the criteria and the headers corresponding columns in the data table

Comment: the default text treatment with advanced filter is "begins with".  For exact match on "apple" use `="=apple"`

Comment: See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59873101/how-to-get-exact-match-data-from-another-sheet

Comment: @TimWilliams, that seemed to do the trick! thanks so much for the quick response and the link for additional info!